# JNA - AMD Overdrive5 API returns null pointer error

Tags: java, jna

I am trying to access the AMD ADL Overdrive5 API via JNA to retrieve temperatures of the GPU in JAVA.
I am able to retrieve the adapter information via the ADL API. But I am having a hard time to retrieve the GPU Temperatures.

The API function is defined as:

```cpp
int ADL2_Overdrive5_Temperature_Get (
    ADL_CONTEXT_HANDLE context,
    int iAdapterIndex,
    int iThermalControllerIndex,
    ADLTemperature * lpTemperature   
)
```

and expects a Pointer to a structure containing two ints.

The code I have is:

```java
public interface ADL extends Library {

    public static class T1Str extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends T1Str implements Structure.ByReference {}

        public int iSize;
        public int iTemperature;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            re  turn ImmutableList.of(
                "iSize",
                "iTemperature"
            );
        }
    }

    public int ADL_Overdrive5_Temperature_Get(
        Pointer context,
        int     iAdapterIndex,
        int     iThermalControllerIndex,
        T1Str.ByReference pointer 
    );

}
```

The actual call of the function is:

```
final T1Str.ByReference str = new T1Str.ByReference();
str.iSize = str.size();
final int result = adl.ADL_Overdrive5_Temperature_Get(
    context,
    adapterIndex,
    0,
    str
);
```

The call always returns -9 as a result which translates into ADL_ERR_NULL_POINTER: Null Pointer error

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.amd.com/display-library-adl-sdk/), it appears that there's two *different*, confusingly similarly named functions:

```
int ADL_Overdrive5_Temperature_Get(
    int iAdapterIndex,
    int iThermalControllerIndex,
    ADLTemperature *lpTemperature
)
```

...and...

```
int ADL2_Overdrive5_Temperature_Get(
    ADL_CONTEXT_HANDLE context,
    int iAdapterIndex,
    int iThermalControllerIndex,
    ADLTemperature *lpTemperature
)
```

As you've probably realized by now, you're accidentally calling the first one whereas you meant to call the second one. Since you pass 0 for the third argument of the *first* function, you're essentially passing `NULL` for the pointer argument.

Include the number 2 in your Java method's name to call the correct function.

```
public int ADL2_Overdrive5_Temperature_Get(
    Pointer context,
    int iAdapterIndex,
    int iThermalControllerIndex,
    T1Str.ByReference pointer 
);
```

By the way, if I recall correctly, JNA passes structure *arguments* `ByReference` by default so you can save some verbosity by just using the `T1Str` class as the the argument's type.

Comment: Very well documented and absolutely correct answer. Also the second suggestion (removing ByReference) is correct and is working fine. Thank you.